# How to group identical elements in Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following:

```
array = ["John", "Mike", "Bob", "Mike", "Bob"]
```

i want to get output:

```
[["Mike", "Mike"], ["Bob", "Bob"], ["John"]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get positive response here, it is best to show what you have tried. You can edit your question to show this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is how to do that in Ruby.

```
array.group_by{ |x| x }.values
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with proc shorthand?

Comment: @maxpleaner you can do `names = ["John", "Mike", "Bob", "Mike", "Bob"]; names.group_by(&:itself).values`